# Binded Datagrid not updating on dataset change

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, dataset, xceed

I created a side panel to search in several databases, which are selected from a combobox in the main menu.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sum.SideRecordSearch"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:xcdg="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid"
             xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"             
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Name="Search_Mode">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource x:Key="Record_Search_DGCVS"
                                            Source="{Binding ElementName=Search_Mode, Path=dataSet}"
                                            AutoCreateItemProperties="True"
                                            AutoCreateForeignKeyDescriptions="True"
                                            DefaultCalculateDistinctValues="False"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
        <xcdg:DataGridControl x:Name="Search_Record" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Record_Search_DGCVS} }"
                              ReadOnly="True"/>
</Grid>
```

I populated the data the first time I run the application with the following code:

```
public partial class SideRecordSearch : UserControl
{
    public DataTable dataSet
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public SideRecordSearch(MainWindow Window)
    {
        this.dataSet = getData(Window.System_Selected);            
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    internal void Change_System_Subsystem(string System_Selected)
    {

        this.dataSet = getData(System_Selected);

        Search_Record.Items.Refresh();
    }

}
```

And in the MainWindow class I put a void method each time the combobox is updated:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
    {

        internal string System_Selected;
        SideRecordSearch Search_Panel;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            System_Selected = ((ComboBoxItem)IP_System.SelectedItem).Name;
            Search_Panel = new SideRecordSearch(this);

            this.QuickPanel.Children.Add(Search_Panel);

        }

        private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                System_Selected = ((ComboBoxItem)System.SelectedItem).Name;

                Search_Panel.Change_System_Subsystem(System_Selected);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

}
```

However, if I change the combobox, the dataset gets updated, but the datagrid keeps showing the original items from the first time the dataset was filled.

Answer (score 0):

Take UpdateSourceTrigger='PropertyChanged'

```
<xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource x:Key="Record_Search_DGCVS"
                                            Source="{Binding ElementName=Search_Mode, Path=dataSet,UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}"
                                            AutoCreateItemProperties="True"
                                            AutoCreateForeignKeyDescriptions="True"
                                            DefaultCalculateDistinctValues="False"/>
```

and  change  staticResource To DynamicResource

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl x:Name="Search_Record" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={DynamicResource Record_Search_DGCVS} }"
                                      ReadOnly="True"/>
```